# how to retrieve images from server using spring boot and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot as backend and reactjs as frontend. I stored images and videos on server. then retrieve it to front end. when using localhost it works properly. but after i deployed this application on ubuntu server i can't preview images.(but image save process success). In ubuntu my spring boot jar file is located at /root/main/test. But uploaded images saved outside root folder(/upload/image.jpg). so i can't retrive this as full url. such as mydomain.com/upload/image.jpg isn't working. how can i get this image using react js

Comment: It's strictly your backend's issue. How are you trying to get the images in Spring? (I mean show some code)

Comment: To serve a file you need a server like nginx or apache installed

Comment: @k-wasilewski    

String[] split = filename.split("primages/");
   String fileurl = split[1];
   Path file = userroot.resolve(fileurl);
   Resource resource = new UrlResource(file.toUri());
   if (resource.exists() || resource.isReadable()) {
    return resource;
   } else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not read the file!");
   }
   
   
   this is how i am retriving image. this returns the image file as resourse

Comment: @Aman  i already used nginx to run my web application. did you mean i need separate nginx service for images??

Comment: one is enough. just provide react with the correct url of the image (which ideally should be done with back-end response). Like this `{...., "thumbUrl": "http://ngnix-addr/url/image.jpg"}` so react can render the image normally. And if you have spring-security, make sure that you allow access to those paths.

Comment: @Aman i tried this. but my problem is i run this website using jar file. And run this using nginx. when i store images in server it stored at server root directory(not in the project location). can i access that that using domain name which i used to run my website.

Comment: it doesn't matter where you put it once ngnix is visible to the public + your upload folder is visible to ngnix. I personally use this approach for one of my projects, running jar and uploads under ngnix(/var/www/hmtl/app-name/uploads)

Comment: did you mean my jar file need to be located at (/var/www/hmtl/). its actually at custom location which is created by me. and images also not saving in this directory. images saved at root directory

Answer (score 0):

You can configure spring boot to serve static content:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:/upload
```

or with code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
      .addResourceHandler("/upload/**")
      .addResourceLocations("file:/upload/");
 }
...
```

Comment: how to get this location using frontend framework. such as image url

Comment: http[s]://domain/upload/folders.../image.extension

Comment: i have react project inside the spring boot as static content. I tried this code. but after build jar file it search for react app in this given location. and also after build jar file there is no directory in server like this. how do i deal with that?